# For loop over index of lists in list - Index out of range

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I don't know how to overcome the index out of range error this time. As my data sometimes contains values and sometimes not and I want to keep the original information about the list index so appending it to a new list wouldn't work.

I'm looking to print every fifth value of the list in list if value three exists.

## Sample Data

```
wks = [["title_01", "value_02", "My Value", "", "value_04"], 
       ["title_02", "value_03", "My Value", "", "value_05"], 
       ["title_03"],
       ["title_04", "value_05", "My Value", "", "value_07"],
       ["title_05", "value_06"]]
```

## My Code

```
for wks_list in wks:
    if wks_list[2] == "My Value":
       print(f"My Values in List: {wks_list[4]}")
```

## Current Result

```
IndexError: list index out of range
My Values in List: value_04
My Values in List: value_05
```

## Result I'm looking for

```
My Values in List: value_04
My Values in List: value_05
My Values in List: value_07
```

Comment: What's `{row[4]}`??

Comment: Sorry writing mistake, updated it.

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: I ran your exact code and it does not throw an `IndexError`.

Comment: The code is not throwing any error please check it again. its giving correct output.

Comment: I'm very sorry guys, my original code is much more complex. The values seem to completely missing and are not only empty strings so I updated the question.

Comment: Now it should be pretty clear what happens, no? What's `["title_03"][2]` supposed to be?

Comment: I know what happens, I only don't know how to work around it. I tried it by checking if the value exists. But this didn't work.

Comment: All of your sub-lists must have *at least* 3 elements or you'll get an index error.  Additionally, if element `[2]` of a sub-list is `"My Value"`, then that sub-list must have *at least* 5 elements, or you'll also get an index error.

Comment: Are you aware how to catch exceptions? You could just handle that `IndexError`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Comment: The 3rd nested list contains only one element and you are trying to access the 3rd element which doesn't exist.

Comment: Again I know what an index error is and usually how to overcome it. But in this case, I don't know how to check only the ones where index 2 exists and still count the index of the lists in list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just catch the potential `IndexError`.

```
for wks_list in wks:
    try:
        if wks_list[2] == "My Value": # IndexError can occur here
            print(f"My Values in List: {wks_list[4]}") # or here
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. Didn't know try will continue if it finds an IndexError!  Thank you a lot for your answer.

Comment: "Didn't know try will continue if it finds an IndexError!"  <- It does not. What do you mean?

Comment: It seems to skip the values with a potential index error which solved my problem :)

Comment: @BenjaminK it continues even if any error occurs. that's the use of try catch

Comment: @BenjaminK For clarity: the code in the `try` block is executed until an `IndexError` occurs. In that case we catch it and do nothing. We do this for every element in `wks`.

Comment: I was thinking way to complex right now. Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: @BenjaminK no problem!

Comment: Sometimes it's good to grab some food instead of sitting 12 hours in front of the screen and be a blockhead. :'D